# How to fix error - Invalid argument: file.contentType, when creating new Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a new Google Sheet in a created folder, but am having issues with the content Type.

I have searched for this error but haven't found anything. Most searches come up with a `MimeType` error, but I don't think that's the issue. Below is the code I'm using:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("MyID").createFolder("New Folder");
newFolder.createFile("myFileName",ss,MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
```

Whenever I run this in my spreadsheet, I get the following error:

> Invalid argument: file.contentType (line 3, file "Code")

I have tried using "" for the content for `createFile`.

Comment: Do you want to convert from spreadsheet to docs? Or do you want to just create new doc? Because in your script, it seems that you want to convert or import data of spreadsheet to google doc.

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I didn't realize that. I meant to create a new spreadsheet. I changed the MimeType to .GOOGLE_SHEETS, but it's still returning the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about following sample? I cannot use MimeType of GOOGLE_SHEETS and GOOGLE_DOCS, too. I don't know why. So I propose use of SpreadsheetApp.create(). The flow is as follows.

1. Create spreadsheet using SpreadsheetApp.create().
2. Add destination folder information to the spreadsheet.
3. Remove original folder information from the spreadsheet.

By this, you can create a spreadsheet to a folder you want.

Script:

```
var sheetfile = "myFileName";
var destfolder = "MyID";
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheetfile);
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId());
var destfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destfolder).addFile(file);
var docfile = file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
```

### Updated: November 25, 2020

At July 27, 2020, the method of `moveTo(destination)` was added. And, the methods of `addFile` and `removeFile` will be deprecated. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#expandable-1) So, when the method of `moveTo(destination)` is used for above script, it becomes as follows.

```
var sheetfile = "myFileName";
var destfolder = "MyID";
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheetfile);
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId());
var destfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destfolder);
var docfile = file.moveTo(destfolder);
```

- When the method of Files: insert of Drive API is used, the following script can be also used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

  ```
    var sheetfile = "myFileName";
    var destfolder = "MyID";
    Drive.Files.insert({title: sheetfile, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{id: destfolder}]});
  ```

Comment: Given the 30-Sep-2020 update of Google drive where every object can have only one parent - I am not sure if this would work - var docfile = file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);

Comment: @Moiz Tankiwala Thank you for your comment. In the current stage, it seems that above script works. But from your comment, I added other patterns in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and instead of trying to create a file on the fly, I thought of having a cleaner solution where by I am keeping one empty spreadsheet (Just create a spreadsheet in the drive and name as "Template") as a template to make copies out of.

```
var templateFileId = "asfashfkhsfkhfkhkashf"; //This is something you have to define as a constant
var destinationFolderId = "sdfashfkhaskf"
var newSpreadsheet = DriveApp.getFileById(templateFileId).makeCopy("NewSpreadsheet", destinationFolderId);
```

Answer (score 1):

this methode work with me

```
function myFunction() {
var sheetfile = "myfilename";
var destfolder = "MYFOLDER";
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheetfile);
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId());
var destfolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(destfolder).next();
var docfile = file.moveTo(destfolder);
}
```

without next(); it not working for me